# What is the name of that milling technique

Tags: milling

I remember a wooden pot-coaster: one side had lateral grooves milled and the other side had the same grooves, but in orthogonal direction. The grooves were deep enough that the grooves met in the middle, producing a matrix of rectangular through holes.

Does this pattern have a name?

Comment: I don't know that the milling operation itself has a name, but the pattern created might be (often?) called a lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Waffle](https://www.google.com/search?q=wood%20%22waffle%22%20routing&tbm=isch) is how I've commonly heard this pattern referred to.